# using free() function in C

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, free

I wrote a function to add dynamically created nodes at the end of a linked list,using malloc.And then on last line of function, I tried to deallocate the memory space for the pointer temp.

```
addnodelast(int data){
struct node* temp =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->data=data;
temp->link=NULL;
struct node*p=head;
while(p->link!=NULL)
{
    p=p->link;
}
p->link=temp;
free(temp);
```

}

But on executing, I am not able to print the list as it is infinitely printing random values.But when i remove/comment the last line free(temp), it works all fine.

Comment: I don't see any prints in this code. Moreover, I don't see anything meaningful at all here.

Comment: It is a logical error to free the just added node.

Comment: You call `free()` prematurely.

Answer (score 2):

You allocated space for a new node & added it to the list; `temp` is pointing to this node.  When you call `free(temp)`, you are not freeing the space *taken up* by temp, but what it *points to*: the very node you just added to the list.

Comment: Yes,after using free(temp), temp will not be pointing to the newly created node.But that should not affect the list as I have already stored the address of the node(p->link=temp).So why my print function is not working on using free?

Comment: What is it that you think `free` does?

Comment: @KrishnaBagaria because the  memory no longer "belongs" to you after `free()`. It can be overwritten by another process.

Comment: @ScottHunter Suppose the address of temp variable is 100 and its content is 200 (which is the address of the newly created node).So free(temp) erases the memory location 200 but not 100?

Comment: @KrishnaBagaria: `free` doesn't "erase" anything; it releases that memory so that it can be used (and modified) elsewhere.  But you are correct in that it does not change the variable containing the address being freed.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not able to print the list as it is infinitely printing random
>   values.But when i remove/comment the last line free(temp), it works
>   all fine.

It's not really surprising. When you `free()` the node you added to the list and then try to print/access it, you are invoking [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the node (its memory been de-allocated) no longer "exist" as far as your program is concerned. So, you those nodes all become [*dangling pointers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

So, you should not free() the nodes until you no longer need to access the list.

Answer (score 1):

after p->link = temp, the value of the temp variable also lives in p->link.

If that address is freed, then p->link will be referencing deallocated memory, which will get reused for other purposes, corrupting the data.